# How do I make the entire world an ocean?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In *Minecraft Java* 1.19.2, I've tried using the Lukewarm Ocean Single Biome world type, but all it does is consider the whole world as a Lukewarm Ocean biome while still generating islands.

Comment: Do you want a world of ONLY water, or water everywhere with caves underneath it?

Answer (score 4):

So what you want to do is go on to **more world options** on the create world. click on the top right button till you see **superflat**. click on the **customise** button, click on **presets** and select **water world**

Comment: Hello again, did this work?

Comment: sorry i shouldve clarified my question better, is there a way to have things like sea kelp, shipwrecks and elder guardians etc. spawn as well, like a naturally spawning ocean?

Comment: @flop00 strangely, the "water world" option should allow those things to spawn naturally. Are you sure you selected the preset? And are you diving low enough for those things to exist?

Comment: You’re right, I don’t think I was diving low enough to find them; I see shipwrecks and stuff spawning now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

an option for daredevils -- 2 ocean monuments, 1 ruin, and 1 suspicious sand and gravel monument thing. The seed is -7300608029358981975   everything is at spawnpoint because given x-ray availability for a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I found some seeds that have water worlds:

**775658584**: This seed is good for exploring underwater structures, such as shipwrecks, coral reefs, and ruins. The ruins contain treasure and are often guarded by guardians.

**30100647980803778592**: This seed places players at the coordinates (X 828, Y 85, Z 4) for a view of a vast ocean biome. Players can dive down to (X 821, Y 48, Z 262) to find a sunken home with a chest inside.

**244235966168137161**: This seed is a water world seed for Minecraft Xbox 360 Edition.

**606175701**: This seed is 98% water and includes almost all ocean biomes

Hope this helps you!